# Testcase creating duplicate entries and deleting mysql database entries when tests are configured to use sqlite

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to seed my tests with data using the TestCase

**TestCase.php**

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected $roleOwner;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->roleOwner = factory('App\Role')->create();

        $this->roleCounsellor = factory('App\Role')->create([
            'name' => 'counsellor',
            'display_name' => 'Counsellor',
            'description' => 'Counsellor on team.'
        ]);
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

**RoleFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(Role::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'owner',
        'display_name' => 'Owner of Team',
        'description' => 'Owner of users team.'
    ];
});
```

When I run all of my tests `vendor/bin/phpunit` I get this error for dozens of tests:

> 21. Tests\Feature\UsersTest::a_user_can_remove_a_counsellor_from_their_team
>     Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'owner' for key 'roles_name_unique' (SQL: insert into `roles` (`name`, `display_name`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (owner, Owner of Team, Owner of users team., 2020-07-07 19:59:43, 2020-07-07 19:59:43))

> Caused by
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'owner' for key 'roles_name_unique'

When I run each test individually everything passes.

Also, when I run all of my tests it deletes everything in my mysql database, and I have my tests configured to run on sqlite. I think that's related, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that the database will be reset after each test. I think the `RefreshDatabase` trait is what you are looking for. See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test).

If you are not using in-memory database in your unit tests then the above trait can running very long time. So you can use the following trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions`. It will run much faster because it does not have to reset the database for each test. It wraps every test in a database transaction and rolls it back afterwards. That way, no actual changes will be written to the database.